# How to make the 'Sign In' link bigger and move it closer to the center of the page rather than the far right where it is in check-out?

Tags: checkout, onestepcheckout, customer-login

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto
all extensions from Amasty
```

The first time I was going through the check-out on Magento 2.4, it took me a long time before I spotted the 'Sign In' link during the check-out process. I thought it was just us (problems with styles/formatting whatever) but I recently seen someone else's screenshot and theirs was the same! It seems not logical to have one of the most important buttons/links hidden too far to the right and to be this small. I'm sure if I originally missed it, customers will too!

**What would be a good solution to bring this to the forefront of customer's attention and how to implement it? (make it bigger, move it more towards the center etc.)**

[image]

Comment: I would just style it via CSS, you can right click and inspect that link to see what classes to target.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css to your checkout page

```
.authentication-wrapper .action.action-auth-toggle {
 float: left;
 font-size: 22px;
}
```